# Long Polling in a Spring REST application

Tags: java, spring, rest, gwt, long-polling

I have an application where the server-side is Spring REST and the client-side is GWT. The client has various different data displays using GWT's DataGrid.

The client is interactive and the user may make changes, and the data and its display grids are all inter-related, so when data on one grid is edited, there must be corresponding updates to other display grids as well.

Furthermore, there may be multiple clients is use simultaneously, all of whose displays should be kept up to date.

To this end, I have been looking at using Spring's long-polling capability to use Servlet 3's asynchronous requests.

I have managed to understand the basics (I think), such that the client makes a request, and the connection is kept open until there is data to be sent (the display update).

As soon as the client receives a response, the displayed data gets updated, and the client them immediately issues another request which is answered when another update has occurred.

So, how does the server know if a request's originating client has already received the latest update?

Comment: Have you considered using WebSockets?  As this will give you a cleaner implementation of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many methods exist in `GWT` for push back services 
like a `GWT Event Services` [enter link description here](https://codeio.wordpress.com/2010/11/16/5-minutes-on-java-gwt-consumer-server-push-tutorial/)

In order for the server to initiate a request to the client, you will need to use `WebSockets`, and experimental `HTML5` feature currently only supported by Chrome.

Or, to simulate this kind of interaction, you can use `Comet (long-polling)`, made available in GWT by the rocket-gwt project.